# how to fetch id 91 from src in php

Tags: php

I have fetch id 91 from this

```
 <img width="526" height="339" style="float: none;" src="http://www.test.com/files/thumb/91/595" class="pyro-image" alt="floyd mayweather">
```

i have tried this using explode and strip tags but not able to get this. its a string which will keep changing according the images.Please help.

Comment: So you have this data as a **string** or what exactly is "this"?

Comment: And what is the logic to target `91` - is it always the penultimate number in the SRC, or what?

Comment: @FelixKling ya its string from which i have get id 91 which will keep changing for individual images

Comment: Are you getting it on the server side (when you request the image) or do you need to get the image ID from the string that you posted?

Comment: @h2ooooooo i need to get this using php ...so i can fetch related data of this id.

Comment: Yes, but do you need to get this from the string you posted (using for example regex) or do you need to get this when you request /files/thumb/91/595 (using htaccess) ?

Comment: no i dont want this to get using .htaccess i will like to get this using any method of php

Comment: @Utkanos ya this id will always come after /files/thumb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then the following regex should work for you (note, [Regex and HTML are not friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but you can use this instead of an HTML parser, if it's not more complicated than this).

A regex of `#<img.*src.*/files/thumb/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).*>#` should work:

```
<?php
    $string = '<img width="526" height="339" style="float: none;" src="http://www.test.com/files/thumb/91/595" class="pyro-image" alt="floyd mayweather">';
    preg_match('#<img.*src.*/files/thumb/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).*>#', $string, $matches);
    echo "Image ID: " . $matches[1] . "<br />";
    echo "Other number: " . $matches[2] . "<br />";
?>
```

Outputs

```
Image ID: 91
Other number: 595
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the string you posted is exactly that - a string. With this in mind:

```
$str = '<img width="526" height="339" style="float: none;" src="http://www.test.com/files/thumb/91/595" class="pyro-image" alt="floyd mayweather">';
if (preg_match('/(?<=files\/thumb\/)[^\/\?]+/', $str, $match))
    echo $match[0]; //91
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code and you can get all parameters --

```
<?php
$html = '<img width="526" height="339" style="float: none;" src="http://www.test.com/files/thumb/91/595" class="pyro-image" alt="floyd mayweather">';
preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $html, $m); 
//echo $m[1][0];

list($par1, $par2, $par3, $par4, $par5, $par6, $par7) = explode("/", $m[1][0]);

echo $par1."   ".$par2." ".$par3."   ".$par4." ".$par5."   ".$par6." ".$par7;
```

Comment: @Pramod anytime bro....chk with this you can fetch all parameter values..edited my code :)